# Plain CSS buttons in different sizes

Tags: html, css

Just a plain button, in different sizes. I wanted to achieve exactly the same styling cross browser for both anchors, inputs and buttons.

I'm just wondering if this could be improved.

**Markup**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CSS button</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" class="button button-tiny button-primary">Sign up</a>
        <a href="#" class="button button-primary">Sign up</a>
        <a href="#" class="button button-medium button-primary">Sign up</a>
        <a href="#" class="button button-large button-primary">Sign up</a>

        <hr>

        <input type="submit" class="button button-tiny button-primary" value="Sign up">
        <input type="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Sign up">
        <input type="submit" class="button button-medium button-primary" value="Sign up">
        <input type="submit" class="button button-large button-primary" value="Sign up">

        <hr>

        <button class="button button-tiny button-primary">Sign up</button>
        <button class="button button-primary">Sign up</button>
        <button class="button button-medium button-primary">Sign up</button>
        <button class="button button-large button-primary">Sign up</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body,
input,
button {
    font: 14px "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
}

input::-moz-focus-inner,
button::-moz-focus-inner { 
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.button {
    padding:8px 16px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-radius:3px;
    border:0;
    margin:0;
}

input[type="submit"].button,
button.button {
    cursor:pointer;
    outline:none;
}

.button-tiny {
    font-size:12px;
    padding:6px 14px;
}

.button-medium {
    font-size:16px;
    padding:10px 18px;
}

.button-large {
    font-size:18px;
    padding:12px 20px;
}

.button-primary {
    background:slategrey;
    color:#fff;
}

.button-primary:hover {
    background:lightslategrey;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the liberty of adding your code to a [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/WbsmE/) so that we could see what it being displayed and test it in different browsers.

---

I tried to set my Browser to IE 8 and less and apparently it doesn't play nice with JSFiddle.  but in IE 9 mode it showed up very nicely, exactly the same as in Chrome.

---

I like that you created a CSS class `button-primary` so that you didn't repeat the code you were going to use in all the buttons. and so you didn't have to write so many `:hover` statements.

---

Overall I would say that this is some pretty clean code.

But, there is one thing that I would suggest that you do.

**Terminate every tag**

This

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
```

Becomes

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
```

Notice the `/>` at the end.  if there is no closing tag you should still "*close the tag*"

these are called Self closing Tags.

some Tags are self closing tags and some are not. HTML5 is a little blurry on this, or I am a little blurry on HTML5

either way you should make sure that these tags

1. `<img />`
2. `<hr />`
3. `<br />`
4. `<input />`
5. `<area />`
6. `<link />`
7. `<meta />`

and some others.   [This Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/97585/1214743) Lists some more

---

XHTML allows you to Self Close any tag, this isn't really good practice, mostly because most tags are meant to be containers and leaving them empty would be really silly.

---

This [more recent answer from BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13232170/1214743) explains a little bit better about closing tags.

I recommend always closing your tags, even if the Doctype tells you that you don't have to. it is better practice.

Comment: Thanks for this feedback! Regarding the self closing tags, I prefer to not self close but I keep this consistent. As you mentioned, HTML5 is a little blurry on this. I think it's preference, to be honest.

Comment: if you ever code for XML or XHTML and you are used to doing this, you will get errors and not know where they came from. it's not a good idea, and shouldn't be your preference, in my opinion

Comment: That's true, and a good point.